# Typescript - returning the constructor of a child class from an abstract method

Tags: typescript, abstract-class

I have abstract class Child and abstract class Parent as follows:

```js
abstract class Child {

}

abstract class Parent {
  abstract getChild(): typeof Child; // <-- want a class that extends Child
}
```

The idea is that both Parent and Child are extended by actual implementation classes, where each implementation Parent knows what its Child class is:

```js
class ActualChild extends Child {

}

class ActualParent extends Parent {
  getChild() {
    return ActualChild;
  }
}
```

As far as TS is concerned, the returned object is of type Child, and thus cannot be instantiated.

I tried many different ways to explain that the function returns only a class that extends Child without success.

Is there any way to type that?

Comment: `getChild(): typeof ActualChild {
    return ActualChild;
  }` ?

Comment: And these concrete subclasses of `Child`... will they all be zero-arg constructors or do they require constructor arguments of some sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare an `interface` to describe the `abstract class Child` itself, and change the return type of `getChild()` to be that interface.

```
interface ChildConstructor {
  new(): Child;
}


abstract class Parent {
  abstract getChild(): ChildConstructor;
}
```

Then this will compile without TypeScript errors:

```
const parentInstance: Parent = new ActualParent();
const ChildClass = parentInstance.getChild();
const childInstance = new ChildClass();
```

Comment: Generics wasn't what I was looking for, since at the level that this code is used, I don't have any specific implementation classes that I can refer. This solution works, if for reasons I don't understand (how is this any different to TS than instantiating Child?). Thanks for the answer, and thanks everyone else for the effort :)

Comment: I do have to complain that it's ugly though, I would have thought there would be some easy built-in syntax for that

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#introduction) and a [new constaint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#using-class-types-in-generics).

```js
abstract class Child {

}

abstract class Parent<TChild extends Child> {
  abstract getChild(): { new(): TChild}; 
}
```

then

```js
class ActualChild extends Child {

}

class ActualParent extends Parent<ActualChild> {
  getChild() {
    return ActualChild;
  }
}
```

[Typescript Playground Approves](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgwgCwJbIBMEBvAKFIF9zRIZ4lV0EAFYKAUwDsIAeAFRz4i7AB4QuBDIMIA+EqQSKENaHEQBzdhGkEAFAEoAXCQSd2AdwPGBeQggoBuSuRRoMAQXgBXYMh0JRcU5JLFsiMmdSVyZPCB9kVg5uALEJDESuXlj4nTkyRU1tMIN5JQQOOKhOBGzfHSdFKgogA)

> As far as TS is concerned, the returned object is of type Child, and thus cannot be instantiated.

This is technically incorrect.  The object returns is class type (the class of child).  Your wording *object is of type Child* typically means *an instantiated object of type Child* which is not correct.

Comment: Just to note, the generics are only necessary if the specialization of the `ActualChild` needs to be preserved, otherwise `abstract class Parent { abstract getChild(): { new(): Child }; }` works just fine. The only difference between that and my answer is an interface providing a canonical name for the `new` constraint.

Comment: Right I assumed that his comment *where each implementation Parent knows what its Child class is* made this a requirement.

Comment: I only took that to mean the return value for `getChild()` in each implementation of `Parent` would be tightly coupled to an implementation of `Child`. I suppose it doesn't hurt to provide the specialization as a generic though.